# When I am trying to update an existing job I get Supply either @job_id or @job_name to identify the job

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I am new to modify existing SQL Agent jobs and I got requirement from my client that I need to rename the job with adding the description to it.

I am trying the below statement but it gives me `Supply either @job_id or @job_name to identify the job.` error.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id='CD63A0B5-522C-495D-BED5-D9F900F71202',
                            @job_name=N'JobName',
                            @new_name=N'NewJobName',
                            @enabled=0, 
                            @description=N'The Description is now available.'
```

I don't know what am I missing over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you need to specify either @job_id or @job_name to identify the existing job, but not both. You can use either of these scripts to accomplish the task:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id='CD63A0B5-522C-495D-BED5-D9F900F71202',
                            @new_name=N'NewJobName',
                            @enabled=0, 
                            @description=N'The Description is now available.';
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=N'JobName',
                            @new_name=N'NewJobName',
                            @enabled=0, 
                            @description=N'The Description is now available.';
GO
```